# How to get the groupedExchanges when there is an exception occurred in the camel split?

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have an aggregation Strategy in my camel split() route.

```java
from("direct:split")
    .split()
        .method(new SplitBean(), "splitMessage")
        .aggregationStrategy(AggregationStrategies.groupedExchange())
        .stopOnException()
    .to("direct:destination")
    .end();
```

The splitMessage method has split the data into 3 request data. So I am hitting the http destination endpoint 3 times.

Using the aggregation Strategy my http response got aggregated for the first 2 times.

Third time when the http call failed with an exception. The exchange returned to the caller does not contain the first two grouped exchanges.

How can I get the grouped exchanges with (success, exception) this case.

Please tell me if the question is not clear.

Comment: This is still a mystery!

Answer (score 1):

1. Change from .stopOnException() to   .stopOnAggregateException()
2. create an AggregationStrategy strategy class and handle the exception from there

   public void configure() throws Exception {

   ```
        from("direct:split")             
                .split()
                .method(new SplitBean(), "splitMessage")
                .aggregationStrategy(new ErrorStrategy())
                .stopOnAggregateException()
                .to("direct:destination")
                .end();

    }

    public class ErrorStrategy  implements CompletionAwareAggregationStrategy {
            @Override
        public void onCompletion(Exchange exchange) {

        }

        @Override
        public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
            if (newExchange.getException() != null) {
                return oldExchange;
            }

            if (oldExchange == null) {
            ....
            return newExchange;
            }
      .....
        return oldExchange;
        }
        }
   ```

Comment: it skips the exception exchange now. but what I am looking for is the exception exchange should be captured and the split should stop(by stopOnException). Is there any workaround you can suggest?